# Delete and Edit a datagrid row using checkboxes in WPF C# (Data coming from database)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently new to C#(WPF) and trying to develop a project and stuck on this point. I want to add checkboxes to each row (and a master checkbox in header). The data is coming from my database into datagrid. I want to be able to check a single checkbox at a time and if I click on master checkbox all other checkboxes should get checked as well. I want to be able to perform DELETE, EDIT to a row. DELETE all selected rows too.
My Sample code for XMAL is:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" ColumnWidth="*"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="9"></DataGrid>
```

My Sample code for CS is:

```
 public void updateDataGrid()
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Zeeshan\Documents\zeemobiles.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

        string query = "Select * from Addphones";

        SqlConnection databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand commandDatabase = new SqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(commandDatabase);
        commandDatabase.CommandTimeout = 60;

        // Let's do it !
        try
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Selected", typeof(bool))); //this will show checkboxes
            
            ad.Fill(dt);

            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            ad.Update(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Show any error message.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            databaseConnection.Close();
        }

    }
```

This is what I have worked out yet from getting help from different webistes.

[image: I have added checkboxes to a column but I don't know how to get there values]

Answer (score 0):

Another better approach would be that you get selected Item from `DataGridView`. And apply operation on that. But for that you would also need to specify the Item Source as well as you will be defining the columns and the data that you'll be binding by using `Binding="{Binding id}"` in `DataGridTextColumn`.

For more:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/how-to-bind-datagrid-in-wpf-using-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IList<ItemViewModel> DataSource { get; }

    public ICommand EditCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }

    private void DeleteCommandExecuteDelegate(object obj)
    {
        foreach (var item in DataSource)
        {
            if (item.IsSelected)
            {
                DataSource.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }

    private void EditCommandExecuteDelegate(object obj)
    {
        foreach (var item in DataSource)
        {
            if (item.IsSelected)
            {
                item.Property1 = Guid.NewGuid();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public object Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataSource}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Checked" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{binding Path=IsSelected"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>    
</DataGrid>
```

Demo

```
DataGrid1.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27840006)

Comment: thanks your comments.I changed answer! @Amir Dora

Comment: The code you share above doesn't links to my question at all. I wanted to have checkboxes and you have used buttons.

Comment: @Zero001 I've modified this logic, and the code I've given is just an example.The actual situation requires you to modify according to your own needs